# MySQL - Update tables using RegEx and database table JOIN

Tags: mysql, regex

We have a database that contains data from a web forum that's about a decade old. We have the database backup and files. However, a lot of the code of the old software used is no longer available, so properly upgrading and then doing an import isn't possible. Instead, we are attempting to manipulate the core data we are interested in (Users/threads/posts), and accept we might end up with something not quite perfect, but under the circumstances, it'll suffice.

A lot of issues I managed to resolve using SQL queries and/or RegEx changes. However, I'm in need to having to combine both, and am uncomfortable with that step.

The old forum used a gallery add-on, the main table of which contains (simplified) an id column, and a link to the actual image referenced by that ID.

Ie.

```
ID                URL
123               bede6fc8edc69d2e5fac760e323d8079.png
```

Whenever a user posted an image in their signature, profile or posts, it'd include a url with the galleryid.

I.e. `[IMG=http://www.example.net/album_pic.php?pic_id=123]`

My goal is to perform a database update using REGEX to identify and links to the gallery (I.e. `http://www.example.net/album_pic.php?pic_id=`, combined with a `JOIN` to the gallery table that essentially performs the lookup to grab the actual image URL.

Is this even possible? If so, could someone nudge me in the right direction on how to approach this, combining the REGEX with a JOIN? My main challenge is that the regex comparison will be done on text data, some of which will include multiple images (I.e. someone posting a tutorial that contains multiple images) within the same post.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide sample data for both tables and expected results.

Comment: @GMB - That's fair. I'll add some of that when I get home. Let me see if I can figure out a way to put the question on hold until then.